# wcf security intranet nettcpbinding client non-domain account - options

Tags: wcf, wcf-security, nettcpbinding

The WCF service is hosted on IIS 7.0. The WCF client is a Windows service running under the Local System Account. Both the service and the client are hosted in the intranet. The binding I am using is the netTcpBinding with Transport security. Message security cannot be used because of Streaming. Certificates cannot be used because of deployment considerations. What are my options to ensure the best possible security in this scenario?

Comment: The best option is using domain account.